# Random numbers when trying to insert a float into a string

Tags: python

In python, I run this simple code:

```py
print('number is %.15f'%1.6)
```

which works fine (Output: `number is 1.600000000000000`), but when I take the decimal places to `16>=`, I start getting random numbers at the end. For example:

```py
print('number is %.16f'%1.6)
```

Output: `number is 1.6000000000000001` and

```py
print('number is %.20f'%1.6)
```

Output: `number is 1.60000000000000008882`

Does this have to do with the way computers compute numbers?

edit: Thanks for all the responses! I understand it now and it was fun to learn

Comment: Yes, it's an issue with floating point math and how computers handle them. See https://floating-point-gui.de/ and many other resources online for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular issue that digital computers have in general and certainly not a bug in Python.

This is caused since internally there's 32/64 bit precision for floating points.

You can read about it in official docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your machine's floating-point arithmetic. Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as binary fractions. Most computers approximate floats by using the first 53 bits for the numerator of the binary fraction. 53 bits equals a 16 digit precision.
So the numbers you get at the end of your displayed float are not actually *random* numbers, but you just see more of the number that your machine came up with to approximate your float.

If you want to look more into this, you can read the [floating point part of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).